# Como accedo a la data que trajo un cursor en una llamada a un sp?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, cursor, toad

tengo una consulta.
Tengo un SP que llama a otro SP, el segundo tiene como parametro de entrada un cursor que hace un select.

Mi consulta es, como accedo desde el primer SP a la data del cursor?

Este es un ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_PRUEBA
(
    PIDBENEF IN NUMBER
)

AS

PCUR  SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

    SP_GETBENEFICIARIO(PIDBENEF,null,PCUR);
    

--Como accedo acá al PCUR??

    FOR item IN PCUR
    
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(item.nombre);
    END LOOP;
    
    
END;
```